# Which hats are awarded at the end of the UTC day?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2013

Which [Winter Bash 2013](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/) hats are awarded at the end of the UTC day as opposed to when they were earned (relatively, since it usually takes a few minutes at least for the quick ones).

Comment: Here's hoping R-E-S-P-E-C-T is one of them, because I rep-capped today and haven't gotten it yet.

Comment: @GenericHolidayName - I guess we will find out in 90 minutes unless you get it before then :)

Comment: @GenericHolidayName: I got my R-E-S-P-E-C-T in the middle of the day, actually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I can tell (aside from sekrit hats) there are only two

- [image]
  UpDo - received only upvotes on a day, from at least five different users
- [image]
  Frosty the Snowman - cast only upvotes on a day, to at least five different users