# What criteria should I fulfill actually for UpDo hat?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2013

I know Winter Bash is not of big importance according to most SO users. However, I have a bet with the bro who is going to win more hats and currently he is so much winning!

I think I should have won at least the UpDo hat: I receive almost only upvotes, after the start of the bash they are literally only upvotes, about 1 per day. However, I used to justify  me not winning the hat with the fact that the upvotes were on answer I posted before I joined the bash.

Yesterday, however, I got an upvote on [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20717402/android-pause-resume-timer-or-thread/20717478#20717478) I posted after I joined the bash. I think this should have gotten me the hat. I woke up this morning hoping to be at least one layer of clothing closer to my bro, but to no avail.

Is there particular number of upvotes on new questions I should get in a day to win this hat?

NOTE: I am marking currently the question as bug, cause I think at least the hat description should be changed, now it gave me fake hopes.

EDIT: After the answers I am sure I am speaking of a small defect in the winter bash. I am reading about the hat descriptions from the tooltips. See here:

[image]

Comment: Tooltip show only summary, to see full description just click the hat and it will appear below the hat. No bug here.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Summary is supposed to be condensed, I agree but it also should summarize, not change the content. I would change it to: "All received votes on a day are upvotes, at least from 5 users"

Comment: Fair enough, but please start new feature request asking to change the tooltip. This current question is bug report that ended up being by design, as all answers explain.

Comment: @ShadowWizard not so. My experience as programmer shows that is fairly often you get wrong string contents opened as bugs. I also think this is the way to treat such. It is just a minor portion of this feature that contains a tiny-winy bug.

Comment: There is no way for a dev reading the title here "What criteria should I fulfil actually for UpDo hat?" to understand he should actually change the tooltip of the hat, and if you change the question you void all existing answers. Do as you please, I just advice what I consider best course of action.

Answer (score 9):

As the hat description says, the criteria is:

> UpDo: received **only** upvotes on a day, from at least five different users

Checking your Stack Overflow profile, I can see that you got 4 upvotes yesterday:

[image]

But you need 5 (and from different users). Continue contributing positively and I'm sure you'll get this hat :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have updated my question to make it clear why i think there is an error in the hat description (at least in tool tip)

Comment: @BorisStrandjev This is the correct answer; the tooltip could probably be a little bit clearer, but it's not meant to replace the complete description that is shown for each hat – the tooltip is just a summary.

Answer (score 4):

> UpDo - received only upvotes on a day, from at least **five different
>   users**

Checking your reputation history, you got maximum of 4 upvotes a day (the hat requires atleast 5 vote)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have updated my question to make it clear why i think there is an error in the hat description (at least in tool tip)

Comment: @BorisStrandjev:  yes, the tool-tip is not correct

Answer (score 2):

Hat summary shows:

> UpDo: received only upvotes on a day, from at least five different users

Some of the hats aren't instant. They take a couple of hours to get to you.
If you feel you've matched this criteria, be patient.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have updated my question to make it clear why i think there is an error in the hat description (at least in tool tip)

Answer (score 0):

Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/212231/178816

The updo hat is only awarded **at the end of the UTC day**, so you must make sure that none of your posts are downvoted for that entire UTC day period.