# What scripts run at 3:00 UTC?

Tags: support, scripts

What scripts (e.g. the serial-voting script) run at 3:00 UTC, as opposed to once every minute, few minutes, or <strike>[6 to 8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/238586)</strike>?

<sup>This question was inspired by a specific thing I encountered: seven posts that I edited were removed at exactly 3:00 UTC, lowering my reputation by 14. While I *did* ask this question to figure out why that happened, it is *not* about that problem and only that problem, so please answer accordingly.</sup>

Comment: A link to one of the questions would help. Old downvoted questions get deleted after a while for instance.

Comment: @juergend I don't have links to any of those questions because they were deleted. You can look at [my rep tab](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/238586), though. It happened yesterday (12/27/13).

Comment: @Ryan In your specific case, seven posts you had previously edited got automatically deleted in the clean-up, and you lost the +2 reputation for each of those suggested edits.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is probably not a complete list, but here are some of the things:

- All tag-related processes. This includes recalculating tag scores, destroying tags that are abandoned, and awarding new tag badges.
- Clean-up of low-quality and abandoned questions. [See what qualifies for automatic deletion.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006)
- Automated reversals of [voting fraud](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me) (serial voting).
- Expiration of old close and reopen votes on questions.

Comment: And certain hats! [Which hats are awarded at the end of the UTC day?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/212230/178816) ;)