# What is the use of a tag with no questions?

Tags: discussion, support, tags

I noticed that there are currently [**two debatable tags**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=new) with no linked questions, and are not synonyms.

[image: Tags]

The purpose of a tag is to help define a post for searching etc.
Why would someone make a tag that does not have any questions, especially ones of this questionable a usefulness?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These tags were created, but the posts they were associated with were either removed, or were retagged.

[This is usually cleaned up at 3AM UTC](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213993/168244).

Answer (score 3):

Tags with no questions will be auto deleted nightly, but not all tags with no questions are really tags with no questions. Closed questions that include those tags will not show up under the normal tag page. You need to search for tag name and include the search operator for closed questions.